# Error entre clase Dao y Bean

Tags: java

tengo un problema me encuentro haciendo un login con jsf e hibernate, hago la consulta entre 3 tablas, pido la id y la contraseña y me devuelve el nombre del cargo y en el bean dependiendo del cargo tiene que ir a una vista distinta, pero hago la consulta en el dao y en el bean manda eso como nulo, cuando pongo la consulta en mysql me muestra las datos y hago un paso a paso en netbeans y trae los datos, no se realmente que puede ser

esta es la clase dao, el metodo donde esta la consulta

```
public Instructor finbyUsuario(Instructor instructor) {
        Instructor model = null;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        String sql = "select cargo.Nombre from instructor INNER JOIN (cargo INNER JOIN asignacion_cargo_instructor ON cargo.CodCargo = asignacion_cargo_instructor.fkCodCargo) ON asignacion_cargo_instructor.fkIdInstructor = instructor.Id where instructor.idInstructor= '"+instructor.getIdInstructor()+"' and instructor.ClaveInstructor='"+instructor.getClaveInstructor()+"'";

        try {
            session.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity("cargo", Cargo.class).addEntity("instructor", Instructor.class).addEntity("asignacion_cargo_instructor",AsignacionCargoInstructor.class);
            transaction.commit();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        return model;
    }
```

y este es el bean

```
private Instructor instructor;
    private UsuarioDao usuarioDao;

    public loginBean() {
        this.usuarioDao = new UsuarioDaoImp();
        if (this.instructor == null) {
            this.instructor = new Instructor();
        }
    }

    public Instructor getInstructor() {
        return instructor;
    }

    public void setInstructor(Instructor instructor) {
        this.instructor = instructor;
    }


    public String login(ActionEvent event) {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesMessage message;
        boolean loggedIn;


        this.instructor = this.usuarioDao.finbyUsuario(this.instructor);

        try{

            if(this.instructor.equals("Líder del programa")){
                    loggedIn = true;
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("instructor", this.instructor.getIdInstructor());
                    return "views/inicio.xhtml";
            }
            if(this.instructor.equals("Instructor Líder de Área")){
                    loggedIn = true;
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("instructor", this.instructor.getIdInstructor());
                    return "views/inicio.xhtml";
            }
            if(this.instructor.equals("Instructor etapa lectiva")){
                    loggedIn = true;
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("instructor", this.instructor.getIdInstructor());
                    return "views/inicio2.xhtml";
            }
            if(this.instructor.equals("Instructor etapa productiva")){
                    loggedIn = true;
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("instructor", this.instructor.getIdInstructor());
                    return "views/inicio.xhtml";
            }
            else {
            loggedIn = false;
            message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Loggin Error", "Usuario y/o Clave es incorrecto");
            this.usuarioDao = new UsuarioDaoImp();
            if (this.instructor == null) {
                this.instructor = new Instructor();
            }

        }

        }catch(Exception e){
            message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Loggin Error", "Usuario y/o Clave es incorrecto");
                }
      return "login.xhtml";
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué utilizas SQL nativo en lugar de HQL? ¿Qué es lo que necesitas obtener de la consulta? Algo me dice que el problema es que tu query está mal armado. Deberías tener al menos `e.printStackTrace()` dentro de la sección `catch (Exception e) { }` para que veas si ha salido una excepción y corregirla.

Comment: Armar la consulta SQL de de esa manera,. concatenando strings ,  es pesima práctica. Te expones a problemas de conversión de datos, sql injections (tal vez no aquí pero sí en general), y sobre todo no permites que se cacheen consultas. Usa preparedstaments. Y, si estás usando Hibernate... pues usa Hibernate, esa implementación de finbyUsuario no tiene nada que ver con la idea de Hibernate.